# Ocaml: Get a list of characters that are between two characters

Tags: ocaml

to clarify my dilemma I'll explain the problem I'm faced with...
Basically, I am being passed a string that can contain single characters or ranges of characters and am trying to return back a list of characters represented by the string I was passed.

Ex. "b" would just give a list ['b'] "a-z" would give ['a' ; 'b' ; 'c' ; ... ; 'z'] and something like "ad-g2-6" would be ['a' ; 'd' ; 'e' ; 'f' ; 'g' ; '2' ; '3' ; '4' ; '5' ; '6'] since there is the character a and the ranges d-g and 2-6. (Also worth noting that something like "a-" would just be ['a' ; '-'] since the range wasn't completed.

My ideas for solving this have come to exploding the string into a list of characters (lst) then pattern matching and building onto an accumulator like

```
let mainfunc str = let lst = (explode str) in
  let rec func lst acc = match lst with 
    | [] -> acc 
    | a::'-'::b::t -> func t (acc @ **SOMETHING TO GET THIS RANGE**)
    | a::t -> func t (acc @ [a])
  in func lst []
```

Anything that could help me get a range between the characters would be great and I'm open to ideas if someone has a better way to go about this problem than what I have set up.

(Also note that my explode function works as intended and converts a string into a char list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrote a successful `explode` function I'll assume that you have no trouble with recursion etc. So the problem might just be a way to talk about characters as values (so you can get the next character after a given one).

For this you can use `Char.code` and `Char.chr` (from the OCaml standard library).

Here's a function that takes a character and returns a list consisting of the character and the next one in order:

```
let char_pair c =
    [ c; Char.chr (Char.code c + 1) ]
```

Here's how it looks when you run it:

```
# char_pair 'x';;
- : char list = ['x'; 'y']
```

(I leave as an exercise the problem of dealing with the character with code 255.)

As a side comment, your approach looks pretty good to me. It looks like it will work.